# Exposing View in Django-Python to delete items

Tags: python, django, security

I'm a newbie in Django-Python, i'm writing a view that expose a method to delete an order by a certain given id, but i'm not sure about the security level of this view, i mean, if a malicious user want to delete an order (or a certain number of orders ) it's able to do it without any problem...

So, i'm struggling in how to organize the view in order to make it callable from the client with the proper security level...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You essentially need to provide a decorator to your function based view or mixin to your class based view depending on what you're using.

There are different options depending on what suits your needs

- [Login required](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required) (obvious)
- [Permission required](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#the-permission-required-decorator) (user must have specific permission)
- [User Passes test](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.user_passes_test) (given user must satisfy a given requirement)
- Custom (your own decorator to do custom things)

All of these will give you the chance to redirect a user, stopping them from being able to use the view

Comment: Thanks dude, you've made my day!